# Can I fork a process inside an Cloud Foundry container

Tags: containers, cloud-foundry

Can I fork, spawn a process inside an app when I push this in the cloud foundry container? I am trying to understand from process isolation, fs isolation, health check, nating and routing how does this work --- and how to reach to the child process listening on a port within the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Each pushed application runs in a separate container complete with its own namespaces, control groups, and resource limits. In particular, both parent and child processes run in the container's PID, mount, and network namespaces (among others).

To reach the child process's port, you need to open the port so it is accessible from the network. I suspect one way to do this is to use an [application security group](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/app-sec-groups.html) since the [container manager's primitive](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/garden/blob/master/container.go#L76-L89) for opening a port is not exposed to end users.